# Assign a separate colour to each author in the todonotes package

Tags: macros, todonotes

The `todonotes` package has options for specifying the author name and also an option for specifying the colour of the individual note.  However my question is that, is there a provision to set a colour for a specific author?

For instance if I use `\todo[author=AK]{simple to do}`, it should be equivalent to `\todo[author=AK,color=green]{simple to do}` and `\todo[author=PG]{simple to do}`should be equivalent to `\todo[author=PG,color=red]{simple to do}`.

How exactly can this be achieved?

Comment: `\newcommand\todoAK[1]{\todo[author=AK,color=red]{#1}}`

Comment: My coauthors and I have used @Fran 's approach for many years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define new meta keys:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\makeatletter
\define@key{todonotes}{AK}[]{%
    \setkeys{todonotes}{author=AK,color=green}}%
\makeatother        
\begin{document}
blub\todo[AK]{something}   
 \end{document}
```